# Jquery template code - unable to understand code

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I downloaded jquery template from below https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/44311232/

I am unable to understand what is the purpose of below code:-

```
$.fn.html = function( value , o ) {
    if (value && value.isTemplate) var value = value.apply( o );

    var r = $_old.html.apply(this, [value]);

    return r;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That code is overwriting jQuerys `.html()` method and checks if the first argument is a function/object with a property `isTemplate`. If so, it calls that function with the second argument and applies the result to jQuery original `.html()` method.

Edit: The code probably throws a warning that `value` is already defined, remove `var` before `value` to fix it.